# How to calculate the amount that exists in 2 different text files

Tags: c#, string, desktop-application

I have my file names with the name

```
PPD_EntryDetailRecord_07192010.txt
PPD_EntryDetailRecord_07182010.txt
PPD_EntryDetailRecord_07162010.txt
```

In that the data will be like

61111111111111111111111111111**2500000000**1111111111111111111111111111111111111111              1
61111111111111111111111111111**5000000000**1111111111111111111111111111111111111111              1
61111111111111111111111111111**6500000.72**1111111111111111111111111111111111111111              1

Now I would like to add all those which were in bold and should display the sum...

Comment: Are you asking a question here? What exactly are you trying to do? What sum? From what values?

Comment: Nothing is in bold, could you clarify, the numbers are surrounded by asterisks (* symbols) ?

Comment: Are those asterisks literal in your file or failed formatting? Are there a fixed number of '1' digits in front? What about data numbers starting or ending with '1' ?

Comment: Seems like a really wicked file format. If possible you should change that, e.g. to .csv or something else which clearly separates fields.

Comment: I removed those extra spaces around the bold text for you. Use `<b>` instead of `**` and the formatting ends up right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can make of it:

```
int start = "61111111111111111111111111111".Length + 1;
int length = "2500000000".Length;


string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
foreach(string line in lines)
{
  string data = line.SubString(start, length);
  double number = double.parse(data, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  // sum it
}
```

Comment: actually i would like to sum the values in the 3 text files then how can i

Comment: @Dorababu: You repeat the last part 3 times.

Comment: A small help i am getting the text files to a list box and if i select multiple files from the list box  and then click on generate i would like to add as above i asked then how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you are after the numbers in italic (not bold), and there are *s in the file, you can get the value like this (quick and dirty example code until you confirm the question):

```
string line = ""; // read a line from the file here
double lineValue = double.Parse(line.Split('*')[1]); // split by "*", get the second element, and parse as a double
```

You'd loop through all lines in the file and add `lineValue` to a sum variable.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi my values are 2500000000 ,5000000000,6500000.72 i would like to sum these